# MySQL updating recurring events

Tags: php, mysql, recurring-events

I've been struggling with this for a while and would love some fresh ideas.

I have an events calendar that has recurring events. I've run into some problems when I try to update recurring events.

I have a simple form where I ask the user for a day of the week and a start date.

I want to get the next day of the week after the start date (no problem here) and update the exiting event that week to the new starting day(still no problem). Then I want to increment all the other events after that to be 7 days after the event before it. (<--problem)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../../config/db-config.php';
    $weekday = $_POST['weekday'];        // day of the week the event should take place on
    $start_date = $_POST['start-date'];      //new starting date of the event 
       if (date('N', strtotime($start_date)) == $weekday)
        {
        $start_date = $_POST['start-date'];
        }
       else
        {
         $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next $weekday", strtotime($start_date)));   //gets the first day of the week after the starting date. First event should start on this day.
        }  
    $start_time = $_POST['start-time'];
    $end_time = $_POST['end-time'];

    $start = $start_date . " " . $start_time;  //'yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ii' format
    $end = $start_date . " " . $end_time;

    $repeats = $_POST['repeats'];             // 1 for repeats 0 for no repeats
    $repeat_freq = $_POST['repeat-freq'];    //7 for 7 days, 14 for 14 days etc
    $parent_id = $_POST['parent-id'];        //common parent_id to the event group

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                        UPDATE events
                        SET  start = :start, end = :end
                        WHERE parent_id = :parent_id AND WEEK(start) =WEEK(:start)");     //This updates the existing event of that week to the new starting date

        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
        $stmt->bindParam(':parent_id', $parent_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        }
```

Now I need to loop through every event (with the same parent_id) after this one and increment it by 7 days (or whatever my repeat_freq is). I've tried using

```
UPDATE events
SET  start = :start + INTERVAL 7 DAY, end = :end + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

but this just updates all the events to 7 days after the new start date and not from 7 days from the last event. If I could put this in a loop without having to reference the specific event id and just go sequentially, that'd be great. I'm open to any solutions though. Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE FOR SCHEMA**

My parent_events table has

```
parent_id (auto increment) | start_date | repeats | repeat_freq |
```

My events table has the following

```
event_id (auto increment) | parent_id | start | end |
```

When a new recurring event is created I insert a row into the parent_events table. I get the new parent_id using lastInsertId() and use it when I insert all of the recurring instances (of that parent event) into the events table. Basically, the events table holds all of the instances of a specific (parent) event.

**UPDATE FOR  WORKING CODE**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT event_id
            FROM events
            WHERE parent_id = :parent_id AND WEEK(start) >=WEEK(:start)");


        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start_date);
        $stmt->bindParam(':parent_id', $parent_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $updateArray = array();
        $last_class = 0;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($last_event != $row['event_id']) {
                $last_event  = $row['event_id'];
                    $updateArray[$last_event] = array('event_id' => $row['event_id']);
            }
        }


        foreach($updateArray as $update){
            $event_id = $update['event_id'];
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                            UPDATE events
                            SET title = start = :start, end=:end
                            WHERE event_id = :event_id");


            $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
            $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
            $stmt->bindParam(':event_id', $event_id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $new_start = strtotime($start . '+' . $repeat_freq . 'DAYS'); 
            $new_end = strtotime($end . '+' . $repeat_freq . 'DAYS'); 
            $start = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $new_start);
            $end = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $new_end);
        }
```

Comment: What does parent_id field refer to?

Comment: I updated the question to give more info. parent_id is a common id shared among all recurring instances of a parent event. That way I can edit just one event using the event_id or all instances of the events by referencing the parent_id

Comment: Why do not you UPDATE all the events with the parent_id WHERE the current Start time > NOW()

Comment: I need to increment each start date by 7 days from the last event. Just updating all of them without some how increasing the start value (either via loop or INCREMENT) won't work.

Comment: What I mean, you need to increment all upcoming events by 7 days. So simply UPDATE events set start=TIMESTAMPADD(week,1,start) WHERE start>NOW() & parent_id=:parent_id

Comment: You can as well change NOW() by the date of the last event if you can extract it.

Comment: I don't need to increment the days from their existing start date. I  get a new start date from the form. I need to update the closest event to that date (which the above code does) and then increment the next event 7 days from that date, and the next one 7 days from that etc..  that's where the problem lies.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is loop through the SET of events via PHP.

I will write below the important pieces of code:

```
$sql='SELECT event_id AS id from events WHERE parent_id=:parent_id AND start=:start
```

Running this Query will get an array with all IDs that required update

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
 }
 $row_date=array();
 $row_date[0]=$start  //get start date
 foreach ($rows as $row)

  $sql_date="SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(week,1,$row_date[0])"; //increment start date by 1 week
  $date =  $mysqli->query($sql_date);
  $row_date = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); //Set the start date as Start date + 1 week to reflect in the next loop.

  $sql_update="UPDATE events SET start=$row_date[0] WHERE event_id=$row['id']";
  $mysqli->query($sql_update);
 end foreach
```

The code my need some adjustment, but I think it helps outlay the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea. Im going to have a go at it this morning. I'll accept if I can get it working.

Comment: Wish you best of luck...If it didn't work, please let me know, we can find a way around.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I changed the code a bit but accepted the answer because it led me down the right path.